# Computing the operator norm

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the normed vector space $E$ of all the polynomials with real coefficients in $[0, 1]$, and the $\ell^2$  norm.
Consider the operator $A: E\to E$ such that $P(x) \mapsto x P(x)$. Calculate the operator norm.

This is my attempt. In $0\leq x \leq 1$ we have
$$
\int^{1}_{0}x^2P^2(x)dx \leq \int^{1}_{0} P^2(x)dx,
$$
which leads to
\begin{align*}
\| A\| &= \sup_{P(x)} \frac{\| xP(x)\|}{\| P(x)\|}\\
&=\sup_{P(x)} \sqrt{\frac{\int^{1}_{0}x^2P^2(x)dx}{\int^{1}_{0} P^2(x)dx}}\\
&= 1
\end{align*}

Is this correct? I am not sure because of the supremum.

Comment: All you have shown so far is that the operator norm is less or equal to 1. Find an example where $\|x P(x)\|=\|P(x)\|$ or a sequence $P_n$ such that $\frac{\|xP_n(x)\|}{\|P_n(x)\|} \to 1$. Also please edit the typo, it is $\|x P(x)\|$, not $\|x^2 P(x)\|$

Comment: You've only shown $\|A\|\le 1.$ You need to do more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you've shown is that $\|A\| \le 1$.  You could try using specific polynomials to get a lower bound. For instance, if $P(x) = x^m$ then $\|P\|_{L^2} = \dfrac 1{\sqrt{2m+1}}$ and $\|AP\|_{L^2} = \dfrac 1{\sqrt{2m+3}}$ so that $$\|A\| \ge \frac{\|AP\|_{L^2}}{\|P\|_{L^2}} = \sqrt \frac{2m+1}{2m+3}.$$

Comment: Since that last inequality should hold for every $m$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{2m+1}{2m+3}} = 1$ then $ 1\leq \| A\|$. Using the previous result that $\| A\| \leq 1$, we can conclude that $\| A\| = 1$. Did I get it right?

Comment: That's the idea!